# Unable to merge partitions in Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I had a hackintosh dual booted with Windows 10 and I decided to get rid of the hackintosh by deleting the partition. I now have unallocated space on my HDD which I want to merge back into my Windows 10 `C:\` drive. This is what my configuration looks like now.

[image]

When I right click my `C:\` drive and click extend I see this window, which isn't seeing my larger chunk of unallocated space. I understand that you can only extend to the right of the current partition though.

[image]

I then tried using Aomei Partition Assistant and found a "Merge" option. I did the following:

[image]

It seemed to have worked so I hit apply and it prompted me to restart my computer so I did. It went into PreOS mode and showed the following screen for a few seconds before continuing the normal Windows 10 boot process.

[image]

After restarting my computer, there were no changes. I would really appreciate some assistance on fixing this issue as I've tried everything I can currently think of.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay let us begin with the hard-disk map of your computer.

[image: Hard-Disk Map]

The Memory is just like a queue, there is a starting point and there is an ending point. So the map shown in the image tells that (partitioned) C: drive starts at some point after the unallocated space, so the start point of that C: drive is fixed.

All you can do now is extend the C: drive, and that is the reason why you're able to see the last 449MB unallocated space but not the earlier one.

[image: Screenshot from the question.]

Because you can extend a partition only from its end point and not the starting point. So you can create another partition now (like D:, E: or any letter of your choice), but merging is not possible.

In case this was you non-OS drive, you could have simply merged the partitions by copying data into the unallocated part of your drive and then merging it using some software, but in this case, your OS cannot be just copied to some other place.

All you can try doing is use some partition merging software for merging the space using some software on internet. I found some and I think [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/merge-partitions-windows-10-0528.html) can help you.

**Edit**: 
Here are the steps that will finally help you get a single drive:

1. Download and install [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/merge-partitions-windows-10-0528.html).
2. When you open it, you'll get a screen showing all your partitions, and unallocated space.
3. Right click on C: drive and select the option merge.
4. A box will open asking you to select the drive you want to merge with, select the unallocated space over there and also give the Drive letter as C: only.
5. The last step, click Apply and then Proceed. This process may take minutes or hours depending on your operation. And once it is complete, your hard-drive map will then have one single C:\ drive.

Cheers. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, can I create a new partition, let's say E:\ in the large chunk of unallocated space, extend that large partition into the C:\ drive and rename the entire chunk to C:\? Please note that Windows 10 is installed on the C:\ drive

Comment: You can create a new drive (just like E:\)  in the large chunk but once you create the drive there will be no unallocated space as the space you want to merge with E:\ is already allocated to C:\ drive. So neither can you merge, nor can you change the Drive letter.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. So as far as I understand there's no hope for getting one large C:/ drive without wiping the HDD and reinstalling the OS?

Comment: There's a hope, I just found out that you can merge two drives and assign the letter C to it. Follow the steps that I'm editing in the main answer.

Comment: @Carpetfizz try the edit section of the answer, this should help you. AOMEI Partition Assistant is a good tool for this purpose and I've used this once, so there's no chance of failure. The only worry is and was - "C: is an OS Drive, " So you'll have to make sure you set the drive letter to C only, the software will take care of rest of the things. :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. However if you see in my original post I have already tried that without success.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I missed it. If you want to try then try allocating that space to some drive with a letter and then do the same procedure. I know it sounds somewhat weird, but it is the only difference I could see between your situation and mine.